# Is the Hogwarts Express visible to muggles when it travels across Britain?

Tags: harry-potter

Can non-magical persons see the Hogwarts Express during its journey to and from Hogwarts?

Comment: I think they can, which is why its a train and not a bunch of thestrels.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it possible for a muggle to follow the train to Hogsmead/Hogwarts, in theory? While the protective wards may keep an idle wanderer from going to Hogwarts, spying a train full of children going there might give someone a reason to keep going.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris, except it's a *steam locomotive*, which would look quite remarkable to late-20th-century muggles. On the other hand, wizards are shown to have a certain disregard for anachronism... bottom line, I don't know if we can reason out an answer without additional Word-of-God information.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible it's visible, since Hermione's parents dropped her off to the train and there was no mention of them NOT seeing it. No direct evidence I'm aware of, though.

Answer (score 3):

### Probably not

Although we lack a definitive answer, there are strong signs indicating that the Hogwarts Express must be concealed, at least while it travels.

First, the Hogwarts Express is an old steam engine in bright scarlet. Presumably this would attract attention if spotted moving across the Muggle countryside. In addition, it runs along a track that presumably is not supposed to exist, which also might be perceived as suspicious.

The [description](http://archive.is/20130109120503/pottermorespoilers.tumblr.com/post/9724970993/history-the-hogwarts-express) of the history of the Hogwarts Express on Pottermore also strongly suggests that some form of concealment is active.

> Where exactly the Hogwarts Express came from has never been
>   conclusively proven, although it is a fact that there are secret
>   records at the Ministry of Magic detailing a mass operation involving
>   one hundred and sixty-seven Memory Charms and the largest ever mass
>   Concealment Charm performed in Britain.

We know that Concealment Charms hide things from visual perception, as illustrated for example by a wizard who escape execution by Concealing his neck, making it appear that he had been decapitated. It seems likely that the enormous mass Concealment Charm could not have been for the purpose of stealing the train (since Memory Charms would have worked well enough for that), but for concealing the train or the tracks on which it ran.

Comment: But would Harry and  Ron been able to see the train or tracks in CoS through a charm? I think the Concealment was for Platform 9 3/4

Comment: @Skooba - Possibly. I feel like the Concealment Charm probably only worked on Muggles.

Comment: Yeah not a whole lot of information on Concealment Charms... Although Ekrizdis did use it to hide Azkaban from muggle and wizards alike, and Harry thought (incorrectly) that Malfoy had tried to use one to sneak the necklace into Hogwarts.